# transfer variable betweet two php page

Tags: php, forms, post, get

i have 3 page the first is html where i use  then i send the data to the second page (php) with post where i have some condition, then i will send the data again for the third php page where i will put it in table (html)
my probleme is the data don't send to the third php page

the 2nd page

```
if(isset($_POST['matier']) and isset($_POST['semaine']))
{
    $matier = $_POST['matier'] ;
    $semain = $_POST['semaine'] ;

    header('Location:EmploiMetierSemaine.php?'.$matier.' & '.$semaine);
}
```

the third page

```
<?php

                $matier = $_GET['m'] ;
                $semaine = $_GET['s'] ;
?>
```

any help please

Comment: What's the data for `$_POST['matier']` and `$_POST['semaine']` ?

Comment: matier is a select button, semaine too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in second page  url should be like this EmploiMetierSemaine.php?m=matier&s=semaine

```
if(isset($_POST['matier']) and isset($_POST['semaine']))
{
    $matier = $_POST['matier'] ;
    $semaine = $_POST['semaine'] ;

    header('Location:EmploiMetierSemaine.php?m='.$matier.'&s='.$semaine);
}
```

Comment: i have the same probleme even i add m and s nothing apear in the third page

Comment: hi  can you tell what the browser link is when auto redirected

Comment: write inside page3  `<?php
                $matier = $_GET['m'] ;
                $semaine = $_GET['s'] ;
echo$matier.$semaine;        ?>`

Comment: i did it no result

Comment: what is the url in the browser after seding data

Comment: i really add it i have only php in the second page

Comment: ok you said you do things with radio elements ...etc    add that page , also  i want to  know if the redirection works ok   whats the url in the browser ???

Comment: i resolve it thanks so mutch for ur help, the problem was in the last condition

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the params as parameters again but only values here:

```
header('Location:EmploiMetierSemaine.php?'.$matier.' & '.$semaine);
```

If you want to pass them as `m` and `s` you have to tell your location header so:

```
header('Location:EmploiMetierSemaine.php?m='.$matier.'&s='.$semaine);
```

Note that I also removed the spaces around the `&` since they don't make any sense in the URL.

Comment: i have the same probleme even i add m and s nothing apear in the third page

Comment: did you verify the values are actually there on the "second page"?

Comment: i just get it by $_GET

Comment: What I mean is that on your second page you get them from $_POST like this: `$matier = $_POST['matier'] ;` - did you var_dump(); them there or something and do they actually contain the values?

Comment: How do you try to check if the values actually are there on the third page or not? From your question it looks like you only assign the values to variables but do nothing with them

Comment: in reality i have a radio button and select menu, so in second page i verify with some condition then a send it to the third page

Comment: then give us full code in second page to tell you where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Nowdays If in same case you need to pass a values to multiple pages consecutive with redirection, maybe it's better to review and redesign your program. in other word it's like you are doing something in wrong way.

However, your 2th page must be somthing like this:

```
$matier = $_POST['matier'] ?? NUll;
$semain = $_POST['semaine'] ?? NUll;

header('Location:EmploiMetierSemaine.php?m='.$matier.'&s'.$semaine);
```

And use `$_GET` on 3th page.